# Python import tensorflow in virtualenv creates segfault

Tags: python-2.7, segmentation-fault, virtualenv, tensorflow

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed tensorflow 0.8.0 (64 bits CPU only) in a virtualenv (using `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`).

Running `python -c "import tensorflow"` gives the following error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, running import tensorflow in a Spyder console (whose interpreter is the virtualenv's one) works fine.

I am sure that the interpreter used is the same in both cases (I have printed `sys.executable`)

Any idea of what's happening here?

**Edit**: Installing tf outside the virtualenv, I can execute `import tensorflow` without any issue.

Comment: might be useful to run under GDB to get stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version of Tensorflow was installed outside of the virtualenv; I uninstalled it and reinstalled tf in the virtualenv. Now everything works fine.